# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Root Redirect for Localized Web Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

Actualy i handle globalization for my ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Web Site by passing culture in the url like

http://mysite.com/en-US/

I use the following Route in Global.asax

```
            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        new
                            {
                                controller = "Home",
                                action = "Index",
                                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                                language = "fr",
                                culture = "FR"
                            });
```

Now i need to redirect users accessing the root of the web site http://mysite.com to the default culture or default browser culture http://mysite.com/en-US.

Actually users got a 404 error when acessing the root url without culture specification.

How can i perform this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really need two routes, in the long form of the route you need a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#0f616ba6-9981-4af2-ab46-a4561505f790) to avoid the routes clashing (actually you may not since you are using a dash "-", as long as you have no dashes  in controller names).  Something like this:-

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{language}-{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        }
    ,
    new
        {
            language = @"[a-z][a-z]|^",
            culture = @"[A-Z][A-Z]|^"
        });

routes.MapRoute("DefaultLocale", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            language = "fr",
            culture = "FR"
        });
```